# readarray combined with find and sort returns bigger array than expected

Tags: bash

I am searching for files of a specific date in a folder with backups. It might happen that there are several files of the same day so i want to read them to an array.

After that i want to get that file which got modified last. So i tried to sort the result of find with `| sort` or `sort -r`.

That works while testing my without read array.

But if i run `readarray -td '' matches < <(find /var/backup/web30/ -regextype egrep -regex .*/web30_2022-07-14_[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz -print0 | sort -r)` on a directory where it should only find 2 files `${#matches[@]}"`is 3!?!

But if iterate the array it only prints 2 lines.

Like this

```
      for r in ${matches[@]}; do
        echo "match: $r"
      done
```

If i get rid off the `| sort -r` it works like expected. The array holds 2 items and the length is shown as 2. What am i missing here? If there are 3 items in the array why cant i dump it?

```
find /var/backup/web30/ -regextype egrep -regex .*/web30_2022-07-14_[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz -print0 | sort -r

result:

/var/backup/web30/web30_2022-07-14_00-12.tar.gz/var/backup/web30/web30_2022-07-14_20-12.tar.gz
```

```
typeset -p matches

result:

declare -a matches=([0]="/var/backup/web33/web33_2022-07-14_00-12.tar.gz" [1]=$'\n')
```

Comment: please update the question to include the output from a) the `find|sort` and b) `typeset -p matches`

Comment: Call the `sort` with `-z` option since `find` is called with `-print0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to `readarray -td '' matches < <(find /var/backup/web30/ -regextype egrep -regex .*/web30_2022-07-14_[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz -print0 | sort -rz)`

It seems (thx for the hint to check typeset of matches!) that before there was a new line added to the results. `sort -rz` seems to fix that. Now working like expected and needed. The first array item is the newest file and count result is right.

Comment: The problem was that `find ... -print0` was outputting null-delimited records (that's what `-print0` does), but `sort` was trying to sort newline-delimited records, and then `readarray -td ''` was trying to read them as null-delimited. This delimiter confusion led to nonsensical results.